# Setting objects group doesn't work

Tags: javascript, raphael

I try to create some arrows so i need to group a rectangle and two triangles and then just clone this thing. Here is how i try to do it:

```
var paper = Raphael("arrows", 960, 100);
var r = paper.rect(10, 10, 10, 50);
r.attr({fill: 'black'})
var p1 = paper.path("M5,10L15,0L25,10Z")
p1.attr({"stroke-width": 1, fill: "black"});
p2 = p1.clone();
p2.transform("t0,60r180");
st = paper.set();
st.push(r, p1, p2);
ar2 = st.clone();
ar2.transform("t30,0");
```

The problem is that this p2 transformed triangle is not copied or at least i can't see it in cloned arrow.
Posted on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/empirik/rFuVy/1/

Comment: Post your sample code somewhere jsfiddle etc  ..so it will be easy to check it out

Comment: I've posted it. Updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved your issue, you might need to change the size of the arrow if you want. But best way is to draw a **`path`** and clone the path instead of creating 3 different shapes and pushing it into the `SET`.

**Here is the code:**

```
$(function(){
    var paper = Raphael(0,0, 960, 100);
    var path = paper.path("M 20 20 L 35 5 50 20 43 20 43 80 50 80 35 95 20 80 27 80 27 20z").attr("fill", "black");

    path2 = path.clone();
    path2.transform("t50, 0");    

});
```

Also you can check out the demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rFuVy/2/)

Comment: Who voted down? WTH? I answered to Dmitry Mikhaylov question.

Answer (score 0):

The Transformed triangle is not included in the clone ar2.

If you just need the arrow to be complete add the following lines to your function :

```
var p3 = p2.clone();
p3.transform("t30,60r180");
```

Comment: But why? Actually, i need to group them all because i need to create a lot of arrows

Comment: I am pretty rusty with raphael . The transformed arrow doesn't seem to be included when you clone the entire arrow , if you use st.push(r, p1) the output is the same . Draw the entire arrow as a single plot and clone it instead of worrying about this [if its urgent].